# Output from Python running on Docker back to host with docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, opencv, docker-compose

Im working on a OpenCv project and as many know, the instalation of that on windows is iritating. So, what i want to do is to run the project in a docker container and *store the output to a folder on the host computer*. In simple terms it is something like this:

1. Program python / opencv code
2. Build Docker image
3. Run Docker image --> Saves the output data somewhere
4. In some way - get access to the output data on host.

Now, i have been trying to find many ways of dooing this, and i will probably at a later time send it using other means. However, for development i need this slightly more direct approach. It also has somthing to do with colaboration with others.

Simple Docker file that can be used as the base:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "./script.py" ]
```

Lets say that *script.py* creates a file called *output.txt*. I want that *output.txt* stored at my E: drive.

How to do this automatically - without having to do multiple comandline operations?

**TLDR;** How to get files from Docker container to host? Goal: File physically stored on E:

Comment: Can you skip steps 2 and 3, and just run the Python program on the host without involving Docker?  What have you already tried?

Comment: You can use the mount E: drive as a volume to the container, then stores the output.txt in the mount point.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. First is to mount a docker volume.

```
docker run --name=name -d -v /path/in/host:/path/in/docker name
```

By mounting a volume like this, whatever you write in the directory you've mounted will be written in the host automatically. Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for more information on volumes.

The second way is to copy the files from a container to the host like this

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```

Check docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) for more info on this.